# ReactJS: Fade in div and fade out div based on state

Tags: reactjs

So, I am trying to fade in and fade out a set of inputs based on what button the user clicks. I tried using jQuery, but, the div was fading in and fading out at the same speed...

I am using es6 classes and react.

What I want is the user to **press a button and the inputs fadeIn. Another button, the inputs fadeOut**. I don't mind using jQuery, but I would like to understand how to do this with react.

```
renderInputs() {
  if (this.state.addType === "image") {
    return (
      <div className="addContainer">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" />
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
     other inputs
    )
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <CSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="fadeInput"
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>

      {this.renderInputs()} // this doesn't work but I want this content to be conditional.

    </CSSTransitionGroup>
  )
}

// SCSS
.fadeInput-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.fadeInput-enter.fadeInput-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.fadeInput-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fadeInput-leave.fadeInput-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just use a conditional `class` and CSS.

Have a `state` variable like `visible`.

```
this.state = {
   visible:false
}
```

And for the other inputs do something like

```
<input className={this.state.visible?'fadeIn':'fadeOut'} />
```

So depending upon the `state.visible` the input will have a `class` of either `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`.

And then just use simple CSS

```
.fadeOut{
     opacity:0;
     width:0;
     height:0;
     transition: width 0.5s 0.5s, height 0.5s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;

}
.fadeIn{
     opacity:1;
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, opacity 0.5s 0.5s;

}
```

So every time the `state.visible` changes the `class` changes and the `transition` takes place. The `transition` property in CSS is basically all the transitions separated by commas. Within the transition the first argument is the property to be modified (say `height`, `width` etc), second is `transition-duration` that is the time taken for the transition and third(optional) is `transition-delay` ie how much time after the transition has been initiated does the transition for the particular property take place. So when `this.state.visible` becomes `true` the `.fadeIn` class is attached to the object. The `transition` has `height` and `width` taking 0.5s each so that will take 0.5s to grow and after it is finished the `opacity` transition (which has a delay of 0.5s) will trigger and take a further 0.5s to get `opacity` 1. For the hiding it's the reverse.

Remember to have the `OnClick` event on the button handle the changing of `this.state.visible`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. The transition doesn't seem to be working. Would having `<div className={this.state.visible ? 'mainDiv' : 'hide mainDiv'}>` cause this problem. The div does hide, but there is no transition... At the same time, this onClick is also causing a jquery animation `$('.mainDiv').stop().animate({ change size });` Now, it would make sense for the `stop()` to stop the fade, but I need to stop to handle double click transitions

Comment: Essentially, I am opening a div by animating it's width and height and then I want to fade in the inputs inside that div

Comment: Why don't you use a pure CSS solution and ditch the jQuery so it doesn't interfere with React? I'll update the answer.

Comment: Can you please make a full codepen example of this? Do you need to wrap in constructor or super props?

Comment: This is just perfect.

Comment: Does this work for props.visible if the prop is changed?

Answer (score 6):

You could also achieve this with CSSTransitionGroup

```
const Example = ({items, removeItemHandler}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="fadeInput"
  transitionEnterTimeout={500}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
        {this.renderInputs().map(function(input) {
          return (
            <div key={input.id} className="my-item" onClick={removeItemHandler}>
              {item.name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When working with React, sometimes you want to animate a component directly after it has been mounted, or directly prior to it being unmounted. 
Like in your example, Let’s say you map over an array of objects and render a list in your application. Now let’s say you want to add animations to fade-in new items that have been added to the array or fade-out items as they are removed from the array.
The CSSTransitionGroup component takes in transitionEnterTimeout and transitionLeaveTimeout as props. What these values represent are the duration in milliseconds of your enter and leave transitions.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to achieve this with styled components...

```
const Popup = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: ${({ showPopup }) => (showPopup ? '1' : '0')};
`;
```

---

```
<Popup showPopup={showPopup}>
  {...}
</Popup>
```