# How do I animate React component upon entering the dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I have code something like this in react

```
{this.state.popoverOpen && <Popover/>}
```

it's easy, but when the component actually appears I want it to come in with opacity changing and animating...
I've been working with react for some time but these cases always leave room for confusion for me...
So whats the best and easy solution? no applying classes work obviously at this point...

Comment: Can you please describe little bit more. What exactly the ask is . As far I know you want react component behaves as lazy load ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transitions. Try adding the `fade-in` to the `className` of `Popover`'s outermost HTML element after adding the code below to the relevant CSS file.

```css
.fade-in {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/rodenmonte/pen/LYpOVpb

Here's a StackOverflow answer showing another (better IMO) way to do this [ReactJS: Fade in div and fade out div based on state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702454/reactjs-fade-in-div-and-fade-out-div-based-on-state)